# Tiktok OAuth v2 request parameters are malformed

Tags: oauth, postman, tiktok, tiktok-api

Trying to migrate from Tiktok's API from v1 to v2 endpoints. Currently version 1 works for me but my request to the https://open.tiktokapis.com/v2/oauth/token/ endpoint keeps returning

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "The request parameters are malformed.",
    "log_id": "202308141814065FE27A58513347021AF1"
}
```

I'm testing this through Postman and here are screenshots of my request:
[image]

[image]

The url used to obtain the "code" passed into the postman request is
https://www.tiktok.com/v2/auth/authorize/?client_key=abcdefg&scope=user.info.basic,user.info.profile,user.info.stats,video.list&response_type=code&state=abcdefg&redirect_uri=https://www.test.com/redirect

I've requested support from Tiktok for the log_id and they say its due to "grant type is not set in request." I'm using applicaiton/x-www-form-urlencoded in Postman's header so if that is the issue I'm not sure what else to modify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is because you're passing the params in the **query** params, **they must be in the body params**:
[image]

you can also try to import this curl in the postman, it's in the official documentation:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://open.tiktokapis.com/v2/oauth/token/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
--data-urlencode 'client_key=CLIENT_KEY' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET' \
--data-urlencode 'code=CODE' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
--data-urlencode 'redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI'
```

reference: https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/oauth-user-access-token-management

Comment: This was it, thank you so much! For other viewers, after this I ran into the error "Authorization code is expired" which was fixed by url decoding my "code" token.

Comment: @AndrewChow hi! I can't seem to figure out where to find/get the "code" token. How do you get this? I just want to post to my own tiktok account, not others. And the redirect_uri as the same as registered in you app right?

Comment: @maurijn.vd After the Tiktok authorize page redirects you to your 'redirect_uri' you should see the code value appended to the browser url. And yes redirect_uri should be the same as registered, something like 'https:// www.mywebsite.com/loginbuttonpage'

Comment: Okey thanks! And is it correct that you can only use an authorization code once? So every time i wanna make a new request i have to 'log in' and authorize my app again?